# automatically create --set-upstream origin doing git push

Tags: git, github

It's annoying I got prompt every time trying to push new branch. For instance, I do this

```
git checkout -b myBranch
git add . && git commit -m 'first commit'
git push
```

but I got this

```
git push --set-upstream origin myBranch
```

is there anyway to skip this?

Comment: You only need to set-upstream once, then you can push it normally every time, dont get why is that a problem?

Comment: @ikiK it is. Because each jira ticket has to be a new branch

Answer (score 20):

You can configure Git with these settings:

```
git config --global push.default current
git config --global remote.pushDefault origin
```

and then you can simply use:

```
git push
```

to push the curent branch to a branch with the same name on the remote `origin`. This does not set the upstream configuration, but it does allow you to push without any other arguments, whether it’s the first time you are pushing a branch or not.

Comment: `push.default` does most of the work here

Answer (score 6):

With the release of git 2.37 in June 2022, you can do so with `push.autoSetupRemote`

```bash
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```